# C#: does 'throw' exit the current function?

Tags: c#, exception, throw

If there is a `throw` statement in the middle of a function, does the function terminate at this point?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, with the exception of any `finally` blocks, or if there is an exception handler within the function that can catch the type of exception you're throwing.

Answer (score 7):

Control passes to the next exception handler (`catch` block) in the call stack, whether that be in the current method or one of its parents. If the `throw` is not encapsulated in a try/catch block, any `finally` blocks are executed before a parent catch block is sought.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it?  :)

I guess the right answer is, it depends.  If you wrapped the throw with a try/catch for whatever strange reason, then no.  If you didn't, then yes, unless you didn't catch the exception somewhere up the call stack, in which case your entire application would crash.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless you catch it or have a finally block:

```
try {
   var foo = 42 /0;
}
finally
{
  // This will execute after the exception has been thrown
}
```

Comment: ... and in the case of the finally, the current method will be exited anyways, i.e., code after would not execute.

Answer (score 0):

It does, yes. It generates an exception that goes up the calling stack.

Comment: is there any equivalent to Java's finally bloc that could modulate this answer ?

Comment: There is, yes. You do get the typical try, catch, finally exception handling higher up the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It will go to the nearest `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

An exception is an event that happened when it wasn't supposed to and so the application does not know what to do with such event. In all OOP languages (that I know of) what the runtime does is to halt the function that called the event and then throw the Exception up the stack until someone knows what to do with it. That is where try / catch blocks come in.